# Diode models explanation

Tags: diodes

Could I have an explanation with diodes? I have the book but using all these different models is somewhat confusing.

I'm having a lot of trouble telling the difference between Vd and Von, and when to use them!

Comment: I think to get a useful answer here, you'd have to show us which models you are talking about - use the Schematic tool and draw them for us and mark the Vd and Von.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing which book you are referring to, I'll try to simplify this...

Look at a cube: it has eight corners. Atoms with eight electrons in the outer shell stack fairly nicely into a "lattice" or 3-d array of cubes.

Atoms with just a few electrons in the outer shell can get rid of them (like the layers of an onion) but then they have a positive charge. Materials like this tend to conduct electricity rather well.

Atoms with *almost* eight electrons can take up extras, but this gives them a negative charge.

OK enough basic chemistry: what happens when you have FOUR electrons in the outer shell? Elements that fit this description are Germanium, Silicon, and Carbon. Most electronics uses Silicon, with a smattering of Germanium, and - in their pure form - these DO NOT CONDUCT. At all.

That changes when you add a tiny amount of impurity. If the impurity has THREE electrons or less, it will snuggle into the silicon lattice and leave a hole. If it has FIVE electrons or more, extra electrons are left over.

Now for the magic: to make a diode, put a slice of P-type and N-type material together. At the junction, the spare electrons move to the adjacent material, cancelling out the holes, and you are left with a thin layer of pure (not conducting) silicon.

If you hook the P-type side to a negative supply and the N-type to positive, you cancel the effect of more of the impurities, and the size of the pure silicon section gets bigger. That's a reverse biased junction.

With FORWARD bias, P-type to positive supply and N-type to negative, applying a voltage will cause the effective size of the pure silicon section to shrink. At a certain voltage Vd or Von, the diode starts to conduct.

Von is the minimum voltage, needed to make the diode conduct. If you increase the voltage, the current increases in a non linear way. Vd is the voltage across the diode, and depends on the current.

**NOTE** I have provided (simplified) descriptions of semiconductors before. Some have been subject to criticism: so check for other, more accurate descriptions than mine.

Comment: OH so a junction is where they meet basically? I am just imagining 2 differnet types of sandpaper together and applying voltage in the forward biased way (P type to pos supply and N type to negative supply) will allow it to conduct, whereas applying voltage int he reverse biased way(P-type to negative supply and N-type to positive) then it will make more "holes" and not conduct?

Comment: Yes. Hook it up right, and a little energy will eliminate the [carrier depleted] zone in the middle. Try going backwards, and you'll get nothing. Try backwards *too hard*, and you get a dead diode.